# how to get the input value into the controller w/o using angular?

Tags: javascript

this is an angular project, but I have a situation in which I need to get the input field value into my controller without using the angular 2-way binding.

the problem is that my input field is being dynamically added to the html with the following code:

```
       $( "#my-input-fields")
          .append( "<li style='height:15px;' >" + " Type the id. code here:" + 
                  "<input type='text' ng-model='c1.myVar' />" +   
                  "</li>" )
                  .css( "list-style-type", "none");
```

despite being added to the html properly, c1.myvar is never populated on the controller no matter what I type inside the input field. in other words, the 2-way bind does not work.

is there a way to activate the 2-way bind of a html variable after I add it dynamically with jquery? also, I wonder if there is an alternative way of receiving the value of c1.myVar as the user types inside it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before appending it to the `DOM` you'll have to do dynamic compilation to be able to get bindings with `$compile`. This is how you do it.

```
var element = "<li style='height:15px;' >" + " Type the id. code here:" + "<input type='text' ng-model='c1.myVar' />" + "</li>"

var compile = $compile(element)($scope);
```

And now you can append it to the element or wherever you want  like

```
$( "#my-input-fields").append(compile )
```

Don't forget to inject `$compile` in your controller